# Post Query not working

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, widgets, categories

I have made a widget in my functions.php, like this:

```
class Categories_Widget extends WP_Widget
{
  function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
            'categories_widget', // Base ID
          ('Categoriën tonen'), // Name
            array( 'description' => ( 'Toon categoriën' ), ) // Args
        );
    }
  function widget($args, $instance)
  {
    extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);

    echo $before_widget;
    //echo "<h1>This is my new widget!</h1>";
    include 'inc/categories.php';
    echo $after_widget;
  }
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', create_function('', 'return register_widget("Categories_Widget");') );
```

Which fully works. In this widget, I include the `categories.php` file, which looks like this:

```
<?php

    $categories = get_categories();

    foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
      ?>
      <div class="categories-block category-<?php echo $category->name ?>">
        <h4><?php echo $category->name ?></h4>
        <ul>
        <?php
        $catId = $category->term_id;
        global $post;
        $args = array( 'category' => $catId );
        $posts = get_posts( $args );
        foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
          setup_postdata($post);
          ?>
          <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a></li>
          <?php
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <?php
    }
```

For some reason, it shows the category name, but not the query I want to create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the type of your $catId, you must use the `cat` parameter.

You can check [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters) the differents parameters allowed.

> cat (int) - use category id.
>
> category_name (string) - use category slug.
>
> category__and (array) - use category id.
>
> category__in (array) - use category id.
>
> category__not_in (array) - use category id.